# How large is my Matrix?

Tags: c++, gpgpu, matrix-multiplication

I am working on a code which has Matrix Multiplication along with other complex mathematical functions like fft,lu,ifft,fftshift etc. What I want to know is when I change my input parameters

- how large is the matrix becoming when I ran the CPU program
- how the memory usage is related with the size of matrix theoretically.
- how much can my 2GB Radeon handle when I use my ported OpenCL GPU code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Memory usage is related to total element number multiplied by datatype byte size. Lets say you have a 1000 by 1000 matrix wtih 4 byte integers, then your matrix data size will be roughly 4*1000000 bytes or 4 Megabytes.
- Probably you do not need to worry about memory constraints while "GPU memory can be virtualized and the driver will swap in/out memory from the GPU when it is/not needed":

  [How do I determine available device memory in OpenCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568115/how-do-i-determine-available-device-memory-in-opencl)