# How to check if GPU memory is available using PyOpenCL

Tags: python, pyopencl

I would like to know if there is a way to check how much GPU memory is available before a function uses it. I have code that often uses 1.5 GB of GPU memory or more, and if something else is using the GPU when my program wants to use it, I get a `MemoryError` exception or something similar.

I would like to implement some sort of code so that I can check to see if the GPU has enough memory available, and if it does, go ahead and run, but if not, wait until it IS available.

(Preferably, I would like to check before trying to use the GPU rather than using a try-except loop and just retrying if it fails)

I checked the PyOpenCL documentation to see if there was something relevant under [device_info](http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/runtime.html#pyopencl.device_info), but I couldn't find any actual descriptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, and is actually a limitation of OpenCL, not just PyOpenCL. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568115/how-do-i-determine-available-device-memory-in-opencl).

On NVIDIA devices, you can use [nvidia-ml-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nvidia-ml-py). Then you can do something like this:

```
from pynvml import *
nvmlInit()
for i in range(nvmlDeviceGetCount()):
    handle = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(i)
    meminfo = nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo(handle)
    print("%s: %0.1f MB free, %0.1f MB used, %0.1f MB total" % (
        nvmlDeviceGetName(handle),
        meminfo.free/1024.**2, meminfo.used/1024.**2, meminfo.total/1024.**2))
nvmlShutdown()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the above answer with python3 and I did not work, however I was able to work around that using the following code.

```
from py3nvml.py3nvml import *
nvmlInit()
deviceCount = nvmlDeviceGetCount()
for i in range(deviceCount):
    handle = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(i)
    gpuUtilization = nvmlDeviceGetUtilizationRates(handle)
    print(f'{nvmlDeviceGetName(handle)} Utilization: {gpuUtilization.gpu}% Memory: {gpuUtilization.memory}%')
nvmlShutdown()
```